# Can't instantiate a Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Since last night, I haven't been able to save a transaction to `Realm` (only trying the default realm). Either the following code fails and executes the `else` block,

`guard let realm = try? Realm() else { return }`

or the transaction write block fails, printing an error out to the console:

`Error occured when attemting to saving transaction. details: Error Domain=io.realm Code=1 "mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory" UserInfo=0x16d17de0 {Error Code=1, NSLocalizedDescription=mmap() failed: Cannot allocate memory}`

I'm pretty lost as to how to go about fixing this, I've got 3.2GB left on the device so there's plenty hard disk space left

Comment: see this link may be help with you https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1159

Comment: How large is the database file itself? Realm will `mmap` the whole file for every thread you have accessing the db.